# Left shift operation on an unsigned 8 bit integer

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift, integer-promotion

I am trying to understand shift operators in C/C++, but they are giving me a tough time.

I have an unsigned 8-bit integer initialized to a value, for the example, say 1.

`uint8_t x = 1;`

From my understanding, it is represented in the memory like `|0|0|0|0|0||0||0||1|`. Now, when I am trying to left shit the variable x by 16 bit, I am hoping to get output **0**. But to my surprise, I am getting `65536`. I am certainly missing something which I am not able to get.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    uint8_t x = 1;
    std::cout<<(x<<16)<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It's a naive question, but it is bothering me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In  this expression

```
x<<16
```

the integer promotions are applied to the both operands. So the result of the expression is an object of the type int.

Try the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>


int main() 
{
    uint8_t x = 1;

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<int, decltype( x<<16 )>::value << '\b';

    return 0;
}
```

Its ouput is

```
true
```

From the C++ Standard (8.8 Shift operators)

> 1. ... The operands shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type and
>      integral promotions are performed. The type of the result is that of
>      the promoted left operand.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, the operand 16 is an integer of 32 bit(assuming an integer to be 32 bit), so, when applying it with x(or 8 bit), it promotes it also promotes it to 32 bit and finally, the result is of type int(32 bit). Am I right ?

Comment: @PankajMishra See my updated post.

Comment: Very clear,now. Thanks. Upvoted.

Comment: Strangely, if you have code like this: `unsigned char value = 255; unsigned char shiftAmount = 24; printf("%d ", (value << shiftAmount) );` you get -16777216 as the output (not 0)

Comment: @bobobobo The operands of the shift expression are promoted to the type int. So the sign bit is set.